# How to debug jnlp application?

Tags: java, applet, config, jnlp

I have a jnlp file for the topcoder arena that I have downloaded from [topcoder](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.topcoder.com/contest/arena/ContestAppletProd.jnlp&ei=9UdWUs2oC8GSyQHG5ICwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEj-9OnLkdRrv4a6yBUfrHj1m1TjA&sig2=kHA9ZVmkFUmocvrfYdnoYw&bvm=bv.53760139,d.aWc).

I have created a new user and copied some(C:\Users\User*) files from old user on a Windows 7 machine. In the old user this applet used to work fine. But in the new user now it's not. It stops while downloading the application or while verifying the application. It seems that I might have not copied some cache files or might have missed some config. files from old user.

I have also tried eclipse plugin for the contest applet. But it's also having the same problem.

I have also tried to download the application using the same jnlp on entirely new laptop and jnlp is working fine on other laptop as well.

I have freshly installed jre. Also tested two other jnlp applications from Sun website. All other are working fine. But only this one is not working.

I have even enabled the logs using javaws. But it's really not very useful.
My ask for help: Can someone please tell me how do I debug this jnlp file which can direct me in the resolution of this problem? I missed couple of competitions. :(

Thanks.

Comment: Also don't brag about reverse engineering the topcoder client - it's against the T&Cs

Comment: Debugging a problem does not necessarily mean reverse engineering, I guess. I just want to understand what is the problem and what can be the possible resolution. As I earlier mentioned it's not an issue with jnlp file but something is wrong with my config.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to start the JNLP using [netx](http://jnlp.sourceforge.net/netx/) library and a small piece of java code:

```
import netx.jnlp.*;

Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
// local jnlp
ApplicationInstance appInstance = launcher.launch( new JNLPFile( new URL( "/tmp/test/blabla.jnlp" ) ) );
// or remote jnlp
ApplicationInstance appInstance = launcher.launch( new URL( "http://blabla.com/test/blabla.jnlp" ) );
```

It can launch the jnlp application/applet in the current JVM and you will see if there are any configuration problems, exceptions... in the console

Comment: nothing happens once, the application is launched. It runs but I don't see anything in the console. Even I checked the method of `ApplicationInstance` but nothing helpful there.